# How to describe a person who withholds information to make the situation seem worse than it is?

Tags: word-choice

What's an appropriate word or a phrase to describe a person or the behavior of the person, who doesn't want to say things that can be advantageous to you, by hiding the truth.

For example if cops inquire someone whether I have the drug habit, and the person chooses to say " I don't know I am not with him all the time" even though they truthfully know I don't do drugs.

Or someone who says his company doesn't pay bonuses to make it like look it's the general truth, even though bonuses are paid every year for 30 years except for the current year.

Comment: Sounds *passive-aggressive* to withhold information or help.

Comment: This doesn't exclusively apply to adventageous information, but "lying by omission" might fit. It is used to describe a situation in which someone doesn't directly lie, but they leave out important information and misrepresent the truth. So, in your second example, someone would be lying by omission if they said they don't get a bonus but leave out the fact that they received bonuses other years.

Comment: *sandbagger*. But that can refer to someone withholding info for any reason.

Comment: Are you looking for a verb, noun, adjective? Word requests usually need a sample sentence demonstrating how the target language is used.

Comment: If the new contributor has not come back by tomorrow, I will VTC as 'abandoned'

Comment: Not specifically looking for a certain part of a speech. Anything that could describe it effectively is fine

Answer (score 1):

That person is a **prevaricator.** He doesn't speak the precise truth.

See: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/prevaricator

Comment: This would benefit from including the definition itself in your answer.  No need to withold that information.

Comment: Thanks. I found it’s close synonym “equivocate” while researching this

Comment: It means _liar_ and that's the right word, if you don't wanna use _asshole_.